# how to make a complex turtle diagram on python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I wanna make a complex diagram using turtle python can someone please help me I don't know where to even start.
I have tried but cos I am new to python I don't know about any of the key terms and what they mean :(

what does this mean?:

```
import turtle
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem**.

Comment: I suggest reading some basic tutorials before making any "complex" things - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Comment: You could start by reading some basic python programing tutorial books, my favorite first book was "think python"(you can find it in google)  you could also see some you tube chanales. And by the way if you want to learn by example turtle module comes with example so got to your idle then go to help and you will find some examples of turtle programs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

```
import turtle

ninja = turtle.Turtle()

ninja.speed(10)

for i in range(180):
    ninja.forward(100)
    ninja.right(30)
    ninja.forward(20)
    ninja.left(60)
    ninja.forward(50)
    ninja.right(30)

    ninja.penup()
    ninja.setposition(0, 0)
    ninja.pendown()

    ninja.right(2)

turtle.done()
```

i mean this is quite cool, and i understand you don't know where to start but at least post some prior knowledge so other users can give you advice to develop your skills

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm really stuck and I found that quite interesting

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question:

> what does this mean?:
>
> import turtle

The `import` command is used to bring additional collections of code into Python for you to use.  The `turtle` library is an example of such -- Python doesn't respond to turtle commands until you bring them into Python via this `import` statement.

There is online [documentation for Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html).  For quick lookups, you can check what you loaded via:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> dir(turtle)
```

and lookup individual functions via:

```
>>> help(turtle.forward)
```

from within the interactive Python shell.